# Spring: Get Bean in main Method fails

Tags: java, spring

I'm relative new to Java and also to Spring Framework. So this is my first Spring App I'm building and I'm experiencing problems with Autowiring my Beans.

My Application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class);
    builder.headless(false);
    ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = builder.run(args);
    AppRepository oAppRepo = ctx.getBean(AppRepository.class);
    // Check the SystemTray is supported
    if (!SystemTray.isSupported()) {
        System.out.println("SystemTray is not supported");
        return;
    }
    CustomTray oTray = ctx.getBean(CustomTray.class);
    }
}
```

My config.xml in ressource folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    ">

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/application.properties"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="app"/>
<import resource="beans/*.xml" />
</beans>
```

My beans/tray.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="customTray" class="app.CustomTray">
    <property name="schedulerThread" value="app.SchedulerThread"></property>
    <property name="commandControlInterface" value="app.CommandControlInterface"></property>
</bean>
</beans>
```

The Error Message I get on Startup:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [app.CustomTray] is defined
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:371)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:331)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:968)
at app.Application.main(Application.java:46)
```

So I don't understand why there is no qualified Bean cause I registered the bean in tray.xml. The CustomTray class is derived from TrayIcon class and creates a TrayIcon nothing special but for completion,
my CustomTray:

```
public class CustomTray extends TrayIcon {

private static final String IMAGE_PATH = "/images/icon.png";
private static final String TOOLTIP = "Test";

private PopupMenu popup;
private SystemTray tray;
@Autowired private AppRepository oAppRepo;

public CustomTray() {
    super(createImage(IMAGE_PATH, TOOLTIP), TOOLTIP);
    popup = new PopupMenu();
    tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
    try {
        this.setup();
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@PostConstruct
private void setup() throws AWTException {

}

protected static Image createImage(String path, String description) {
    URL imageURL = CustomTray.class.getResource(path);
    if (imageURL == null) {
        System.err.println("Failed Creating Image. Resource not found: " + path);
        return null;
    } else {
        return new ImageIcon(imageURL, description).getImage();
    }
    }
}
```

I got the App running before, without using Autowiring and Beans but now I want to refactor and setup a clean Spring App, I hope heres somebody who knows what I'm doing wrong.

edit:
Ok so now if I'm Importing the xml-Files with the annotation mentioned by UUID I get another Error Message. The bean customTray got two properties, the SchedulerThread property shall be a Singleton Bean, too. It's declared in beans/scheduler.xml which itself also got a property which shall be a bean. like that:

scheduler.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="schedulerThread" class="app.SchedulerThread">
        <property name="processManager" value="app.ProcessManager"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'app.ProcessManager' for property 'processManager'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [app.ProcessManager] for property 'processManager': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

What is the best way to wire these classes and create the Beans? As I sayed I'm new to Spring and I think I didn't understood the way it's working with beans and autowiring.

Answer (score 1):

In SpringBoot application, you need to specify the resources using `ImportResource` annotation

```
@ImportResource(locations = { "classpath:config.xml", "beans/tray.xml" })
```

[Spring Boot documentation - XML configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-importing-xml-configuration)

You can get the bean names using

```
Arrays.stream(ctx.getBeanDefinitionNames()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to remove the XML-Config Files and create an AppConfig-File, now my Application.java look like this:

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class Application {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class);
            builder.headless(false);
            builder.run(args);
        }
    }
```

And AppConfig like this:

```
    @Configuration
    public class AppConfig {
        @Autowired
        GridFsTemplate gridFSTemplate;

        @Autowired
        AppRepository appRepository;

        @Autowired
        UserRepository userRepository;

        @Bean
        ProcessManager processManager() {
            return new ProcessManager();
        }

        @Bean
        SchedulerService schedulerService() {
            SchedulerService schedulerService = new SchedulerService();
            SchedulerService.setProcessManager(processManager());
            SchedulerService.start();
            return schedulerService;
        }

        @Bean
        CustomTray customTray() {
            if (!SystemTray.isSupported()) {
                System.out.println("SystemTray is not supported");
                return null;
            }
            CustomTray customTray = new CustomTray();
            customTray.setSchedulerService(schedulerService());
            customTray.setAppRepository(this.appRepository);
            try {
                customTray.setup();
            } catch (AWTException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return customTray;
        }

        @Bean
        GridFSController gridFSController() {
            GridFSController gridFSController = new GridFSController();
            return gridFSController;
        }
    }
```

Now I can access all these Beans with Autowired annotations and I don't need that context.getBean() stuff. It reduced the code much and I think its the cleaner solution.